# VBA Web page scrape finishes before page loads

Tags: vba, excel, scrape, pageload

I'm doing a web scrape in VBA (see code below) to btc-e.com to fetch prices of some Cryptocurrency. When to it manually by going to data tab and then clicking on from web It works fine, but When I do it in the Macro I only get back "please wait..." 
The page displays "please wait..." as it loads and the macro assumes that is the entire page. 
I have been looking for a way to make the macro wait for the full page load and cant find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(connection:="URL;https://btc-e.com", _
                                 Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "btc-e"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False ' was true
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False ' True ' was false
    .WebDisableRedirections = False 'True ' was false
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
```

Comment: BTC-e has an API. Depending on what you need it may be worth looking into. https://btc-e.com/api/documentation

Comment: Yea I found that out after I had my code done. I don't want to redo everything with the api if I don't have to. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Domain now legally seized and closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a specific table or area of the page you want scraped, otherwise it won't work. The reason is that you are automatically forwarded from the page you are trying to scrape to the page you can actually scrape.

When I chose to scrape the Sell Orders, this is the code I got from the macro recorder:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://btc-e.com", _
    Destination:=Range("$B$2"))
    .Name = "btc-e"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "3"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

As you can see it takes the attribute ".WebTables" which chooses a specific portion of the site. You can choose the portion you want by activating the macro recorder, scraping it through the normal way, choosing the area you want and then looking at the value of WebTables in the resulting code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No that did not do it for me. It will work if i do it by hand first but after I reopen the sheet I get nothing. Thanks for the input.